# How can we login to Outlook using VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

How can we login to Outlook using Excel VBA?

If we have multiple usernames and passwords in an Excel sheet, can VBA code login to Outlook and send mails?

```
Sub Mail()
Dim myApp As Outlook.Application, mymail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim path, path1, path2, emp_name, subject, cc, body As String
Dim file, username, passwrod As String
Dim x, lastrow As Long
On Error GoTo ExitSub
lastrow = Sheets("Mail").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For x = 2 To lastrow
    path1 = Cells(x, "A").Value
    path2 = Cells(x, "B").Value
    path = path1 & "\" & path2
    emp_name = Cells(x, "C").Value
    subject = Cells(x, "D").Value
    body = Cells(x, "E").Value
    cc = Cells(x, "G").Value
    username = Cells(x, "H").Value
    Password = Cells(x, "I").Value
    Set myApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set mymail = myApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    mymail.To = Cells(x, "F").Value
    If path <> "" Then
        If (Cells(x, "F").Value) <> "" Then
            With mymail
                .Session.Logon username, Password, False, False
                '.Display
                .cc = cc
                .subject = subject
                .Attachments.Add path
                .HTMLBody = "Hi " & emp_name & "," & "<br>" & "<br>" & body & "<br>" & .HTMLBody
                .Display
                .send
            End With
        Else
            MsgBox ("Please Enter Mail ID")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox ("Please check Path and File Name")
    End If
Next x
Set myApp = Nothing
Set mymail = Nothing
ExitSub:
End Sub
```

I expect the code to login to Outlook with the details that are provided in the Excel sheet and send mail automatically.